# MutableLiveData NullPointerException Warning

Tags: android

In the MVVM structure, while using the MutableLiveData, even I put an initial value, I got the warning of Unboxing of '`loream.getValue()`' may produce 'NullPointerException'. What is correct way of using `getValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java;l=320?q=LiveData) of `LiveData#getValue()`, you can see it can return null:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Nullable
    public T getValue() {
        Object data = mData;
        if (data != NOT_SET) {
            return (T) data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So you always have to account for that fact.  You didn't specify if you were using Kotlin or Java (or *how* you're using `getValue()` for the matter), so it's hard to tell.

In general, the value(s) of a LiveData stream are often observed and so you wouldn't likely get a null value if you don't "post (or set)" one.

Post a more concrete example if you're looking for specific advice.

If you need a sample, [Google has one here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-livedata#0).